# Left join failing with invalid identifier

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I am doing a full outer join and it's failing with `"ORA-00904: "TABLE2"."PID": invalid identifier"`

Not sure what am I doing wrong here.

See the Sqlfiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b6883/12

Comment: I suggest you to read Oracle documentation about quoted and unquoted identifiers. There are two pages maybe.

Comment: Please show us the code. You surely had code, before you got an error. Show it to us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't enclose column names in quotes. If you use double quotes you are telling Oracle to use the exact case in queries. If you don't use the same case in your queries, it will fail.

See here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0af94/1/2

You DML should be:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1(pid int, seqno int, thing1 int);

INSERT ALL 
    INTO Table1 (pid, seqno, thing1)
         VALUES (1, 1, 300) 
    INTO Table1 (pid, seqno, thing1)
         VALUES (2, 1, 400)
SELECT * FROM dual;

CREATE TABLE Table2 (pid int, seqno int, thing2 varchar2(1));

INSERT ALL 
    INTO Table2 (pid, seqno, thing2)
         VALUES (1, 1, 'a')
    INTO Table2 (pid, seqno, thing2)
         VALUES (1, 2, 'b')
    INTO Table2 (pid, seqno, thing2)
         VALUES (3, 2, 'z')
SELECT * FROM dual;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0af94/1/2

Answer (score 1):

Since you have used quoted identifier during table creation, all your columns have been created in lower case

`CREATE TABLE Table1
    ("pid" int, "seqno" int, "thing1" int)`

So you need to use quoted identifier in your select statement also

`SELECT COALESCE(Table1."pid",Table2."pid") as pid,
COALESCE(Table1."seqno", Table2."seqno") as seqno,
Table1."thing1",
Table2."thing2"
FROM Table1 FULL OUTER JOIN Table2 ON Table1."pid" = Table2."pid";`

See fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b6883/24